# Installing Lxqt on top of Kubuntu 18.04 I have no wifi indicator in panel

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, indicator, lxqt

***This is a QnA ~ Posted in order to provide an answer.***

---

Installing LXQT on top of Kubuntu 18 I have internet connection but I cannot see details about it nor can I see a list of available networks.

I am trying to see the wifi and other internet options on the panel, but all I could find is that I can add a panel widget.

[image]

But that doesn't provide a way to select between wifi networks.

Maybe I haven't installed all the needed programs.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to install the package `nm-tray` and add it to the startup list of programs.

```
sudo apt install nm-tray
```

[image]

After a while the available wifi networks may become hidden with only the "active" and the "known" being displayed.

[image]

You can display them all again

- by clicking on your network listed under "Wi-Fi connection(s)" or under "Known connection(s)" thus resetting the connection (disconnecting & re-connecting to the same network) and displaying the list.
- by clicking on your network listed under "Active connection(s)" thus going offline and displaying the list

---

Another solution is `wicd`. It is very reliable but a bit different from the normal panel tools. It takes some time to list the available networks as it scans for them, also it takes some time to connect after suspend. Another problem is that is seems to inhibit `networkmanager` from running: logging out of Lxqt into Plasma while Wicd is not yet started there, you will have no network connection until Wicd is started.

---

After using Wicd for a while now I prefer nm-tray.